# upload a file on a page with multiple option (button)

Tags: watir

when we have multiple button to upload on a page , I want to upload a file for the 2nd one,we I try to upload so it just upload on the first option.

```
@browser.file_filed(:type => 'file').set 'path'
```

upload_button1        upload_button2    upload_button3

Comment: Hi. Could you provide a code example of your issue and explain what you are trying to do in relation to this code example?

Comment: You've misspelled `file_field`, and it would be better to locate via id (or another somewhat unique locator), if possible.  Otherwise, you can use multiple locators, including an index locator: `@browser.file_field(:type => 'file', :index => 1).set 'path'`

Comment: Thank you so much , I tried this method - the Issue is system can not locate to the button or input - when I click manually on the button(activate the button) then this code work, I tried to locate the mouse point on the button and then upload - so far I can not move the mouse point to the button -

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce this behavior?  Right now, it's a bit of guesswork.

Comment: Thank you all, I found the solution, the application had 2 upload button in a single 'form' . in this case you can not upload directly because the file_filed run on the fisrt upload option and does not matter if you mentioned the id of the 2nd upload option, when all uploads are on a single form the value of 'action' attribute is active on the first option then you need to right a code to change the attribute ot call 2nd service and then write the :@browser.file_field(:type => 'file', :index => 1).set 'path' . I wrote the below code and it works :

Comment: element = @browser.form(:id => 'x')
    sleep 1
  #  puts element.attribute_value('action')
    script = "return arguments[0].action = '/put the value of the second option of action attribute'"
    @browser.execute_script(script, element)
  #  puts element.attribute_value('action')
    @browser.file_field(:type => 'file',:id => 'value of the input').set 'path'